# Eating more calories to improve performance?

Tags: exercise, calories

I have been struggling to make progress in my swimming for quite a while now. Is it simply a need to eat more food to improve? I recently took 2months off swimming to assist my recovery. I want to achieve my goals in swimming, but I don't know if it is that simple to just eat more, becasue I feel like I'm already eating too much?

Comment: As asked, I don't see how this question could be answered in a reasonable way.

Comment: Eat to support your goals. You didn't list anything about current exercise levels, current calorie intake, or type of food you are eating, tough to answer.

Comment: Current exercise levels - 3 times/week for 2hours each
Very high intensity
current calorie intake: would probably vary from 2000-2500
I tend to eat way less on days I don't work out, which is probably not a good habit but I feel like I don't need all those extra calories

Comment: @DaveNewton - I don't really understand how it couldn't be asked in a reasonable way?

Comment: @Bee thanks for clarifying, but could you put those details into your original question?

Answer (score 3):

Your current calorie intake is low.

How many calories do you need per day?

- Your BMR is around 1400 ([estimated from here](http://www.bmi-calculator.net/bmr-calculator/)).
- From the [Harris-Benedict equation](http://www.bmi-calculator.net/bmr-calculator/harris-benedict-equation/), if you did no exercise, you'd require about 1700 calories, just to maintain your current weight.
- Based on [estimates from livestrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/547350-calories-burned-snowshoeing-vs-swimming/), swimming for two hours burns around 700 calories at your weight (taken from [your other question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/will-weight-gain-improve-performance-in-competitive-swimming)). For intense workouts, this is higher, around 1000 calories.
- **On workout days, the *estimate* is 2700 calories just to maintain your weight. On non-workout days, the *estimate* is 1700 calories just to maintain your weight.**
- You should **consume more than the minimum** if you want your body to adapt to your training stresses and improve from workout to workout.

You need calories to support your activity on workout days, and you need calories to aid in recovery on  rest days.

Try eating about 3000 calories on workout days, and 2000 calories on non-workout days for a few weeks and see how that affects your recovery and performance. You may gain a bit of weight, but nothing drastic, and it may be muscle. If you find that the extra calories help your performance, you can fine-tune it from there to find exactly how much you need.

***What* you eat is also important**. This article on [Recovery Nutrition for Athletes](http://athletics.macalester.edu/custompages/Deno_Videos/nutrition/recovery_nutrition.pdf) gives some advice about what types of food to eat immediately after workouts:

> Research indicates that the ideal recovery nutrition is a meal or
>   liquid supplement containing high-glycemic carbohydrates and quality
>   proteins in approximately a 4:1 ratio, that include  10 – 20% of the
>   athlete’s total daily caloric intake of these two macronutrients.

That's just one example, but **choosing the *right* calories** is important throughout your day, not just after workouts.

Here are some other resources to help you sort out your diet:

- [USA Swimming's Nutrition Centre](http://www.usaswimming.org/DesktopDefault.aspx?TabId=1546&Alias=Rainbow&Lang=en)
- [Examples of recovery snacks](http://www.usaswimming.org/ViewNewsArticle.aspx?TabId=1635&itemid=4437&mid=11779) (from USA Swimming) that meet the carb/protein suggestion
- [Pre-workout foods](http://www.usaswimming.org/ViewNewsArticle.aspx?TabId=1635&itemid=4360&mid=11779) (from USA Swimming.. suggested for any workouts longer than 45 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

You answered your problem right away when you stated you took 2 months off of swimming and have been swimming in a "very high intensity" state quickly stagnated.  Very strong case of early over-reaching which can lead to a very fast plateau.  Depending on your work capacity and training volume from the past was, making substantial progress will most likely take a while.  And diet is just a SMALL part of this; if anything it is your training regiment, intensity level, technical considerations.  Diet is just the icing on the cake.

Eating extra calories will give you energy but at what cost?  You put your body through a *shock* now that you have been going into a very high intensity training program.  Your insulin levels will most likely be ping ponging for the first few weeks and weight lose or weight gain will happen; and it probably won't be good weight.  The trick is slowly increasing your volume along with your caloric intake over the course of a few weeks.  Set yourself a goal (either an upcoming competition, summer "fit" look, or for your girlfriend's birthday) and increase your workouts along with your intensity at a slower rate.  It is best to undertrain than to overtrain sometimes which will help you push through plateaus better.  You can try to test your fitness every 2 to 4 weeks by doing a high intensity timed workout to see how you measure in performance (400 Meters for a Personal Best timed for e.g.).

To also answer your question about caloric intake you mention you eat less on non-workout days and more on workout days.  This is termed as carb cycling (even though you mention it as calorie cycling) and does work when done right.  Instead of getting down to the bodybuilding exact numbers and percentages for carb cycling (from the looks at your post you aren't at that level yet), let's keep it simple.  On workout days eat more carbs, keep your protein and fat intake the same and on non-workout simply cut down your carbohydrate intake and slightly increase your protein intake.  Try to minimize the carbs the later it gets in the day (for dinner limit your carb intake for e.g.).

Concerning *right calories* you need to realize that all carbs are broken down into sugars into the body.  The refined carbs (white bread, white rice, etc...) spike the insulin to a higher degree than complex carbohydrates which helps moderate your insulin spike.  If you moderate that correctly that is what will cause you to burn fat, build muscle and improve performance.

Understand though that it is an accumulation of *everything* not just diet that can stagnate performance.  Work, stress from relatives/girlfriends, environment, weather, etc. has an effect.  Understanding how to cope with those variables at the highest level is what creates a champion athlete.

Comment: From one of Bee's other questions, we know she is a competitive swimmer with a coach, so the training program is probably appropriate.

Comment: @Sancho If she has an appropriate coach and program then she wouldn't be asking such an amateur question.  I would think if she had a coach he should be giving her the information to overcome stagnation... Hence I am assuming her program isn't well structured.

Comment: Why can't a person with a coach and training program have nutritional questions?

Comment: I'm not challenging that.  I'm answering your assumption that her coach is "appropriate".  A lot of people seem "appropriate".  You seem "appropriate" to give professional advice.  Take what you want from my post; I'm just giving my two cents of what COULD help.

Comment: @Andreas I fail to see how this is an amateur question? I am asking about the relationship between calories and performance, nothing having been said about the coach's role in this situation. And I can tell you now that my program is well structured and my coach has a great program. To be honest, this is not an amateur question and you should think twice about your future posts and the impact they have on offending people ...

Comment: @Bee I apologize for being so dramatic.  Your post felt like you were *quote* "struggling" as you gently put it.  Therefore I assessed your answers as a mild case of overreaching with a helpless structure of a program.  Maybe displaying more information about your specific program, diet, day schedule could assist in a better answer, and not result in people in this forum upstaging one another based on complete general assumption of your program.  Trust your coach who knows you best, and take other people's information with a grain of salt.